# Fix false(?) warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms

Tags: c#, .net, cross-platform

Why does my code produce the warning "CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. '...' is only supported on: 'windows'? In the method called, there are no windows specific calls at all (indeed, there are only simple arithmetic statements):

```
public static int Mod(this int k, int n) { return (k %= n) < 0 ? k + n : k; }

dividend.Mod(divisor)  //underlined with warning CA1416
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the root cause of the problem. Just in case anyone else runs into it: In the .csproj file, there was no reference to windows; however, the project had an AssemblyInfo.cs included. This contained the line:

```
[assembly: SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
```

I assume this was because of some old references that were not necessary any more.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check your .csproj of your project.
in this case of 2 différente projects the warning msg appear.

solution:**TargetFramework must be The Same.**

```
proj1.csproj
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

proj2.csproj
    <PropertyGroup>
            <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

TargetFramework must be The Same

Answer (score 0):

I was also running into this issue. For me what I had to do was add an `if` statement and check that the OS was windows. I did that using this: `OperatingSystem.IsWindows()`

Example:
 `if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows()) { // error throwing code }`