# CA1416 warnings when using .NET 8 with WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core, .net-8.0

I have an older WinForms application that I'm updating from .NET 6 to .NET 8.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But now I get hundreds of errors, such as the following.

> 3>C:\Users\jwood\Source\Repos\SoftCircuits\HtmlMonkey\TestHtmlParse\HtmlVisualizer.cs(92,21,92,40): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'ListView.Items' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
> 3>C:\Users\jwood\Source\Repos\SoftCircuits\HtmlMonkey\TestHtmlParse\NodeVisualizer.cs(157,30,157,62): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection.Add(string?)' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
> 3>C:\Users\jwood\Source\Repos\SoftCircuits\HtmlMonkey\TestHtmlParse\NodeVisualizer.cs(154,13,154,27): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'ListView.Items' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
> 3>C:\Users\jwood\Source\Repos\SoftCircuits\HtmlMonkey\TestHtmlParse\HtmlVisualizer.cs(86,21,86,33): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'TextBox.Text' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
> 3>C:\Users\jwood\Source\Repos\SoftCircuits\HtmlMonkey\TestHtmlParse\NodeVisualizer.cs(157,30,157,46): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'ListView.Columns' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
> 3>C:\Users\jwood\Source\Repos\SoftCircuits\HtmlMonkey\TestHtmlParse\NodeVisualizer.cs(158,17,158,29): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'ColumnHeader.Width' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)

I don't really understand what is going on here. My solution includes non-WinForms projects, but I don't see how that could cause this error about being reachable on all platforms.

I tested and it works fine with `net7.0-windows`. I'm running on Windows 11.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error with .NET 8?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix C# Warning CA1416 in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734906/how-to-fix-c-sharp-warning-ca1416-in-vscode)

Comment: There's also this where an AssemblyInfo.cs file had data in it which caused a conflict: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70860700/fix-false-warning-ca1416-this-call-site-is-reachable-on-all-platforms

Comment: @GSerg: It doesn't explain why .NET 8 is different from .NET 6 or 7. And it doesn't explain the underlying issue. It does offer a suggestion, which appears to be available on those earlier versions.